# Post with no tag permalink problem

Tags: permalinks, customization, urls, tags

Firstly my problem was the `%tag%` in the permalink, but I resolved it with this patch:
[%tag% in permalink not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/tag-in-permalink-not-working/7132#7132)

So my custom structure now looks like this:

```
/%category%/%tag%/%postname%/
```

And the url is like:

```
/category_name/tag_name/post_name`
```

However, now I have something else that I can't resolve. When post doesn't have any tag the url becomes:

```
/category_name//post_name
```

.. which is undesired.

If post does'nt have tags, i would like the url to be..

```
/category_name/post_name
```

and if it does..

```
/category_name/tag_name/post_name
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to solve this, because `/some-category/some-tag/` will be used as an overview page for all posts in category `some-category` and with tag `some-tag`. If an URL like `/cocktails/bloody-mary/` comes in for a post with the name `bloody-mary`, category `cocktails` and no tags, WordPress can't split it up correctly because at that time it does not know that `bloody-mary` is not a tag, and should thus be a post name.

The best solution is to use a fixed string when there is no tag (`untagged`, like `uncategorized` is what I used in [my answer to your related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/tag-in-permalink-not-working/7324#7324)).