# How to use first tag in permalinks

Tags: permalinks

i have tried `%tag%` in permalinks but it dont showing tag name in the permalinks... What i wanna do is to use the first tag name in the permalinks. So, how to do it? Thanks

Comment: maybe try @JanFabry's answer here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/tag-in-permalink-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `add_rewrite_tag()` to register the placeholder, and filter `post_link` to insert the correct tag. Use `get_the_tags()` to get the tags for a post.

Sample plugin I have used in a project:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Tag as rewrite tag
 * Description: Use <code>%tag%</code> in permalinks.
 * Version:     2012.09.02
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * Licence:     MIT
 * License URI: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

add_action( 'init', array ( 'T5_Rewrite_Tag_Tag', 'init' ) );

/**
 * Adds '%tag%' as rewrite tag (placeholder) for permalinks.
 */
class T5_Rewrite_Tag_Tag
{
    /**
     * Add tag and register 'post_link' filter.
     *
     * @wp-hook init
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        add_rewrite_tag( '%tag%', '([^/]+)' );
        add_filter( 'post_link', array( __CLASS__, 'filter_post_link' ) , 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Parse post link and replace the placeholder.
     *
     * @wp-hook post_link
     * @param   string $link
     * @param   object $post
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function filter_post_link( $link, $post )
    {
        static $cache = array (); // Don't repeat yourself.

        if ( isset ( $cache[ $post->ID ] ) )
            return $cache[ $post->ID ];

        if ( FALSE === strpos( $link, '%tag%' ) )
        {
            $cache[ $post->ID ] = $link;
            return $link;
        }

        $tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );

        if ( ! $tags )
        {
            $cache[ $post->ID ] = str_replace( '%tag%', 'tag', $link );
            return $cache[ $post->ID ];
        }

        $first              = current( (array) $tags );
        $cache[ $post->ID ] = str_replace( '%tag%', $first->slug, $link );

        return $cache[ $post->ID ];
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply... understanding  my level.. i'm just a beginner in wp ... so will you tell me where to edit this codes, or any articles...

Comment: [Install the code as plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web/72183#72183), then go to `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and use `%tag%` as placeholder like `%postname%` or `%year`.

Comment: hello, i am facing a new kind of problem while a post has multiple tags, the first tag i have put to use in permalinks is not working either other tags are being  used in tags.... any idea what to do? Thanks

Comment: @Hasan I don’t really understand what you are trying to say. Please try my latest plugin [T5 Rewrite](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite/downloads) and use `%tag%` as placeholder in your permalink settings. That should work.

Comment: ya,, your plugin is great .. how to use the `%_custome_%` permalinks settings in email posting? I am posting in my wp blog through email using postie plugin....

Comment: For that you would have to save your choice somewhere, in a post meta field for example, and parse that value in `filter_post_link()`.

Comment: can you answer the second question please... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72200/how-to-use-first-tag-in-permalinks#comment97929_72205

Comment: Click the **Help** tab.