# Multiple Tags Issue in Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I have configured `%tag%` for permalinks in wordpress Here is [How to use first tag in permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72200/how-to-use-first-tag-in-permalinks). But while posting multiple tags in a post i am facing a kind of problem.
Suppose i have wrote three tags for a post, they are: `Backlinks, All About SEO, Web Promotion`
So here i wanna use the first tag name only in permalinks, but the problem is all tags are sorted by character in a post, so unfortunately in permalink it will use `www.example.com/All About SEO/page/` though i want to use the first `tag` in permalinks,so in this case desired permalink should be like this: `www.example.com/Backlinks/page/`
**So, how to use the first tag name for the permalinks** please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a column in the [`term_relationships`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_term_relationships) table for `term_order` which seems to imply that one could set the order of terms.  That said, it looks like it doesn't actually work -- the core doesn't use it in any way.

A bit of poking around in [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms), the function that get's used to assign terms to objects (post types, users) revealed this little gem:

```
<?php
$t = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
if ( ! $append && isset($t->sort) && $t->sort ) {
    $values = array();
    $term_order = 0;
    $final_tt_ids = wp_get_object_terms($object_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'tt_ids'));
    foreach ( $tt_ids as $tt_id )
        if ( in_array($tt_id, $final_tt_ids) )
            $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%d, %d, %d)", $object_id, $tt_id, ++$term_order);
    if ( $values )
        if ( false === $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO $wpdb->term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) VALUES " . join( ',', $values ) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE term_order = VALUES(term_order)" ) )
            return new WP_Error( 'db_insert_error', __( 'Could not insert term relationship into the database' ), $wpdb->last_error );
}
```

Which makes it appear that one could set the `sort` argument on taxonomies to true and WP will sort things for you.  The `sort` argument seems undocumented, but a bit of test code reveals that it does indeed work.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse72703_modify_tags', 100);
function wpse72703_modify_tags()
{
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->sort = true;
}
```

The only thing you'll need to do differently in the [using tags in permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72205/6035) is to change this:

```
$tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
```

to...

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag', array(
    'orderby' => 'term_order',
));
```

Which will force the returned terms to respect the order in which you added them.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. I have added it to my plugin now. See [download](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite/downloads).

Comment: Awesome!  I was actually planning on sending you a pull request about that later tonight.