# How to use all tags in post permalinks

Tags: permalinks, tags, urls

My site with pictures is set up so that the posts do not have a title and have only tags.

I would like to know how to use all tags in permalinks settings?

Comment: You could also use my plugin [T5 Rewrite](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite) and add `%tag%` to your permalink structure.

Comment: Be is it possible to use all tags (we have a max limit of 5)

Answer (score 0):

To use *all* tags in a post permalink, try a variation of my similar answer for [How to use first tag in permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72200/how-to-use-first-tag-in-permalinks)

- `add_rewrite_tag( $tag, $regex )` adds a new placeholder you can use in *Settings/Permalinks*.
- The filter on `post_link` translates the placeholder into something useful, here a list of all tag slugs, separated by a `-`.
- Adjust the static variables `$default` and `$placeholder` to your needs.
- Then install and activate the code as a plugin, go to *Settings/Permalinks* and use the new placeholder like this:

  > [image]

```php
add_action( 'init', array ( 'T5_All_Tags_Permalink', 'init' ) );

/**
 * Adds '%tag%' as rewrite tag (placeholder) for permalinks.
 */
class T5_All_Tags_Permalink
{
    /**
     * What to use when there is no tag.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $default = 'tag';

    /**
     * Used in Settings/Permalinks
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $placeholder = '%tags%';

    /**
     * Add tag and register 'post_link' filter.
     *
     * @wp-hook init
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        add_rewrite_tag( self::$placeholder, '([^/]+)' );
        add_filter( 'post_link', array( __CLASS__, 'filter_post_link' ) , 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Parse post link and replace the placeholder.
     *
     * @wp-hook post_link
     * @param   string $link
     * @param   object $post
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function filter_post_link( $link, $post )
    {
        static $cache = array (); // Don't repeat yourself.

        if ( isset ( $cache[ $post->ID ] ) )
            return $cache[ $post->ID ];

        if ( FALSE === strpos( $link, self::$placeholder ) )
        {
            $cache[ $post->ID ] = $link;
            return $link;
        }

        $tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );

        if ( ! $tags )
        {
            $cache[ $post->ID ] = str_replace( self::$placeholder, self::$default, $link );
            return $cache[ $post->ID ];
        }

        $slugs = wp_list_pluck( $tags, 'slug' );
        $cache[ $post->ID ] = str_replace( self::$placeholder, join( '-', $slugs ), $link );

        return $cache[ $post->ID ];
    }
}
```